# SWRevealViewController: Size of FrontView (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

How can I resize Front View of SWRevealViewController like this?

[image]

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578415/modify-frame-of-the-frontview-in-swrevealviewcontroller

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175982/how-to-show-resized-sidebar-using-swrevealviewcontroller

Comment: In a delegate method:

    revealController.rearViewRevealWidth = 300

Comment: @SivajeeBattina - thats rearview, not a front view

Comment: No. In storyboard, rearView is MenuView, frontView is ViewController. That is properties of SWRevealViewController.